# Knapsack (multi-criteria)

Tags: dynamic, knapsack-problem

If I have a knapsack where weight w have **two values v1 and v2** and capacity is m. How will I find the total values for v1 and v2 where the weight does not exceed capacity m?

Comment: Your question is not completely specified. One can understand it in multiple ways. Are there only 2 types of "objects" which can be put into the knapsack (with weights w1 and w2)? Maybe add some example what you mean.

Comment: items:  1 2 3 4
weight: 5 2 4 3
value1: 1 3 5 2
value2: 6 3 2 4
maximum capacity, m= 6. so this means that the bag can carry weight that is equal to or less than 6.

select items 2 and 4, therefore weight = 5:
so for value 1 = 5 and value 2=7.

Comment: Ok, got everything but the last sentence "so for value 1 = 5 and value 2=7"; Where do 5 and 7 come from?

Comment: Got it... it's (weight[item#1]+value1[item#1]) and (weight[item#2]+value2[item#2]). Correct? --- Now, what do you want to maximize? The whole thing (weight[item#1]+value1[item#1]+weight[item#2]+value2[item#2]) ???

Comment: value1 =5 and value2 = 7 comes from:
value1 => weight of item[2] + weight of item[4] because m=6 and 2+4=6. so we add the values of item[2] and item[4]
for values 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your problem is defined as following. First some (variable definitions with sample values):

```
int N = 4; // number of items to choose from
int m = 6; // maximum weight in knapsack

// weight for an item[i] to be summed up, upper limited = m
int weight[N] = {5,2,4,3}; 

// two values for each items:
int values[2][N] = {
  {1,3,5,2},
  {6,3,2,4}
};
```

The knapsack is to be filled with the items, without exceeding weight "m" for the sum of weight for all items in the knapsack. Where you have 2 values for each item. We could regard this problem like:

I want to go on vacation by plane with my girlfriend. And we have one suitecase (=knapsack) and N items to choose from. Each item has a weight and the sum of the weight may not be too height (e.g. weight limit air line is 25 kg and suirecase is 1kg, so we have m=24 kg as a limit for items). For each item we have 2 values. The values[1][N] are the values for me (for having item n in the knapsack on our tour). The values[2][N] are the values for my girlfriend, who has different preferences. We also assume, that every item can be put only once into the knapsack and that the overall value of the knapsack is the sum of their values for me added to the sum of their values for her.

This problem can easily converted to the standard knapsack problem by just adding up the values-list. So an item gets an overall value (e.g. for me and her together) and we only have one value for one item:

```
int value[N] = {(1+6),(3+3),(5+2),(2+4)};
```

Or just:

```
int value[N] = {7, 6, 7, 5};
```

Now you have only -one- value for each item. Which is the normal knapsack problem.

How to solve the usual knapsack problem optimally is described on Wikipedia. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem -- If English is not your mother tongue, also take a look at a version in your language (choose language from the menu there).

If you need further assistance, just ask.

Comment: i want an optimal solution. the problem is like: items:  1 2 3 4
weight: 5 2 4 3
value1: 1 3 5 2
value2: 6 3 2 4
maximum capacity, m= 6. so this means that the bag can carry weight that is equal to or less than 6.

so the output should be like:
select items 2 and 4, therefore weight = 5:
so for value 1 =5 and value 2 =7.